# How to get the actor system reference from inside the actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor, throttling

I have an akka actor that send messages to itself:

```
  def receive = {
    while (...) {
       self ! "some message"
    }
  }
```

I want to use a Throttler to control the flow of messages that this actor sends to itself.

```
  val throttler = system.actorOf(Props(new TimerBasedThrottler(15 msgsPer (1.minute))))
  throttler ! SetTarget(Some(self))
```

and then change the while loop to send messages to throttler:

```
    while (...) {
       throttler ! "some message"
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access the "system" from inside the actor, to create the throttler. How to do this? Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 13):

Inside actor, use context.system to access ActorSystem.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you create the throttler as a child actor?:

```
def receive = {
    val throttler = context.actorOf(Props(new TimerBasedThrottler(15 msgsPer (1.minute))))
    throttler ! SetTarget(Some(self))
    while (...) {
       throttler ! "some message"
    }
}
```

Since it makes no sense to let the Throttler alive if the computing actor is dead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`context`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/ActorContext.html):

```
val throttler = context.actorOf(Props(new TimerBasedThrottler(15 msgsPer (1.minute))))
```

Answer (score 4):

In Akka you can create an Actor with an Actor System or with an Actor Context, like in:

```
class FirstActor extends Actor {
  val child = context.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "myChild")
  // plus some behavior ...
}
```

`context` is a variable available to every Actor.

In case you create the actor with an actor Context it becomes a supervised child of the creating actor, please refer to [Akka Docs about supervision](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html#supervision) and [Actor Creation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html) for further information.